# Undefined Constructor Java

Tags: java

I wrote a small program which has three classes: `Carpet`, `Calculator` and `Floor`.

The carpet class will be called to be multiplied with the floor class by using the calculator class in the main. However, I found that when using double as a return type in the calculator class I came across constructor undefined error.

I found out to be the issue of the calculator class I have a method `getTotalCost()` to return the cost of floor and carpet. why can't I just pass two objects as a parameter in calculator when called in main. I used primitive return type of double in calculator class.

Please help me rewrite the calculator class and explain to me why I can't use the primitive types class but instead, I must use the class name in the calculator field declaration of floor and carpet. Why must the class name for floor and carpet to be passed into the constructor in order to build the object? What is the fix in `getTotalCost()` as if you use the class name to declare two instance fields then surely the error will be something like this:

```
- The operator * is undefined for the argument 
    type(s) Floor, Carpet
- Occurrence of 'carpet'
- 1 changed line
```

Trying to use the classes created but received an error.

```
Carpet carpet = new Carpet(3.5);
Floor floor = new Floor(2.75, 4.0);
```

passing floor and carpet in the parameter of calculator.
//constructor not defined Calculator calculator = new Calculator(floor,carpet);

```
public class Calculator {

    private double floor;
    private double carpet;

    public Calculator()
    {
    }

    public Calculator(double floor, double carpet) {
        this.carpet=carpet;
        this.floor=floor;
    }

    public double getTotalCost() 
    {
        return (this.floor*this.carpet);
    }
}


public class Floor {

private double width;
private double length;

    public Floor()
    {
    }

    public Floor(double width,double length)
    {
        this.length=length;
        this.width=width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) 
    {
        if (this.width < 0) {
            this.width=0;
        }
        else {
            this.width=width;
        }
    }

    public void setLength(double length) 
    {
        if (this.length < 0) {
            this.length=0;
        }
        else {
            this.length=length;
        }
    }

    public double getArea() 
    {
        return (this.length * this.width);
    }
}


public class Carpet {

    private double cost;

    public Carpet()
    {
    }

    public Carpet(double cost)
    {
        this.cost=cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) 
    {
        if (cost < 0) {
            this.cost=0;
        }
        else {
            this.cost=cost;
        }
    }

    public double getCost() 
    {
        return this.cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Calculator(double floor, double carpet)` takes two `double` arguments. Not an instance of `Floor` and an instance of `Carpet`.

Comment: **@Elliott Frisch** is correct. And that's why, it is looking for other constructor.Try to define your constructor as `public Calculator(Floor floor, Carpet carpet) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Calculator` class has only the default constructor (one without any args) and a constructor that only accepts `double, double`, you can't create a `Calculator` instance providing a `Carpet` instance and a `Floor` instance.

So you have 2 options:

1. Pass the floor area and carpet cost to the current constructor.

   `Calculator calculator = new Calculator(floor.getArea(), carpet.getCost());`
2. Change the constructor to accept a `Carpet` instance and a `Floor` instance (then your `Calculator` class logic also should be modified)

```
public class Calculator {

    private Floor floor;
    private Carpet carpet;

    public Calculator() {
    }

    public Calculator(Floor floor, Carpet carpet) {
        this.carpet=carpet;
        this.floor=floor;
    }

    public double getTotalCost() 
    {
        return (this.floor.getArea() * this.carpet.getCost());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of the Calculator class is `(double, double)` so it will not accept Floor and Carpet objects. You can either call the constructor like:

```
Calculator calc = new Calculator(carpet.getCost(), floor.getCost());
```

Or change the constructor to the following:

```
Calculator (Floor f, Carpet c) {
    this.floor = f.getCost();
    this.carpet = c.getCost();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot multiply objects. Looks, like you wand to multiply **carpet** on a **floor** and get... Something? This is not working like this, think about it a little deeper - the fact is you really want to multiply the carpet square (*number* of square meters to be more specific) on cost of 1 square meter (*number* of currency). When you understand this, you should have no trouble to correct your code, so the `Calculator would have`Floor`and`Carpet` fields and be able to calculate total cost based on floor **square** and carpet **cost**  @Udith Gunaratna answered